# How to set a default value for empty/missing POST fields?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a lot of `$_POST` elements and want to insert them into the database, but I must set a default value of "NA" when a user doesn't fill in the form.

This my code:

```php
$tgl_real   =  $_POST['TGL_REAL'];
$rid        =  $_POST['RID'];
$mesin      =  $_POST['MESIN'];
$shift      =  $_POST['SHIFT'];
$produk     =  $_POST['PRODUK'];
$tanggal    =  $_POST['HT'];
$no_aduk    =  $_POST['NO_ADUK'];
$sho        =  $_POST['SHO'];
$tb1        =  $_POST['TB1'];
$gr1        =  $_POST['GR1'];
$tb2        =  $_POST['TB2'];
$gr2        =  $_POST['GR2'];
$tb3        =  $_POST['TB3'];
$gr3        =  $_POST['GR3'];
$tb4        =  $_POST['TB4'];
$gr4        =  $_POST['GR4'];
$tb5        =  $_POST['TB5'];
$gr5        =  $_POST['GR5'];
$spr_besar  =  $_POST['SPR_BESAR'];
$spr_kecil  =  $_POST['SPR_KECIL'];
$br1        =  $_POST['BR1'];
$br2        =  $_POST['BR2'];
$br3        =  $_POST['BR3'];
$tebal1     =  $_POST['TEBAL1'];
$tebal2     =  $_POST['TEBAL2'];
$tebal3     =  $_POST['TEBAL3'];
$panjang    =  $_POST['PANJANG'];
$lebar      =  $_POST['LEBAR'];
$diameter   =  $_POST['DIAMETER'];
$kc         =  $_POST['KC'];
$kkc        =  $_POST['KKC'];
$kerataaan_poles  = $_POST['KERATAAN_POLES'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO adonan SET `RID` = '$rid',
    `MESIN` = '$mesin',
    `SHIFT` = '$shift',
    `HARI_TGL` = '$tanggal',
    `TGL_REAL` = '$tgl_real',
    `PRODUK` = '$produk',
    `NO_ADUK` = '$no_aduk',
    `KERATAAN_SHO` = '$sho',
    `TEBAL_SHEET_GR1` = '$tb1',
    `KECAPATAN_KAIN_GR1` = '$gr1',
    `TEBAL_SHEET_GR2` = '$tb2',
    `KECAPATAN_KAIN_GR2` = '$gr2',
    `TEBAL_SHEET_GR3` = '$tb3',
    `KECAPATAN_KAIN_GR3` = '$gr3',
    `TEBAL_SHEET_GR4` = '$tb4',
    `KECAPATAN_KAIN_GR4` = '$gr4',
    `TEBAL_SHEET_GR5` = '$tb5',
    `KECAPATAN_KAIN_GR5` = '$gr5',
    `SPEED_ROLL_BESAR_WC` = '$spr_besar',
    `SPEED_ROLL_KECIL_WC` = '$spr_kecil',
    `BERAT1_ADONAN` = '$br1',
    `BERAT2_ADONAN` = '$br2',
    `BERAT3_ADONAN` = '$br3',
    `KETEBALAN1_ADONAN` = '$tebal1',
    `KETEBALAN2_ADONAN` = '$tebal2',
    `KETEBALAN3_ADONAN` = '$tebal3',
    `PANJANG_ADONAN` = '$panjang',
    `LEBAR_ADONAN` = '$lebar',
    `DIAMATER_ADONAN` = '$diameter',
    `MOLDER_SPEED` = '$kc',
    `KONVEYOR_SPEED` = '$kkc',
    `KERATAAN_POLES` = '$kerataaan_poles',
    `PROSENTASE_POLES` = '$prosentase_poles',
    `KERATAAN_GULA` = '$kerataaan_gula',
    `PROSENTASI_GULA` = '$kerataaan_gula'";
```

That $_POST is geting data from a form, but how do I set a default ("NA") value
in my database when a user doesn't fill in a value?

I have tried to set a default value in my database, but it didn't work when a user doesn't fill in, my column field is still empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In php 5 you can use [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

```
$tgl_real = isset($_POST['TGL_REAL'])? $_POST['TGL_REAL']:'NA';
```

in php 7, you do not need isset(), you can use ??:

```
$tgl_real = $_POST['TGL_REAL']?? 'NA';
```

You can also use [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) to check POST data is empty or not.

```
if(empty($_POST['TGL_REAL'])){
  $tgl_real = 'NA';
}else{
  $tgl_real = $_POST['TGL_REAL'];
}
```

In fact, you can set [default Constraint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html) in mysql and check to set `NOT NULL`

Answer (score 1):

a simple work around will be you can go with a conditional statement on assignment

```
$tgl_real = isset($_POST['TGL_REAL'])? $_POST['TGL_REAL']:"NA";
```

Comment: that is only use If statement, I have a lot of variable, any Idea  for more simple?

Answer (score 1):

Practically, most of the answers here are vulnerable or require quite a bit of copy paste. Here's how you can make variables on the fly using only the keys you want.

Though, especially as you're inserting them to DB you should consider using arrays instead.

```
$keys = array(
    'TGL_REAL',
    'RID',
    'MESIN',
    'SHIFT',
    'PRODUK',
    'HT',
    'NO_ADUK',
    'SHO',
    'TB1',
    'GR1',
    'TB2',
    'GR2',
    'TB3',
    'GR3',
    'TB4',
    'GR4',
    'TB5',
    'GR5',
    'SPR_BESAR',
    'SPR_KECIL',
    'BR1',
    'BR2',
    'BR3',
    'TEBAL1',
    'TEBAL2',
    'TEBAL3',
    'PANJANG',
    'LEBAR',
    'DIAMETER',
    'KC',
    'KKC',
    'KERATAAN_POLES',
)

$beforeExtract = array();

foreach ($keys as $key) {
    if (array_key_exists($_POST[$key]) && !empty($_POST[$key])) {
        $beforeExtract[strtolower($key)] = $_POST[$key];
        continue;
    }
    $beforeExtract[strtolower($key)] = 'NA';
}

// Make variables from array
extract($beforeExtract);
```

Comment: hey it work, but still little wrong, My database now always fill "NA". Is i must put query after extract($beforeExtract);?

Comment: the query is so simple, only insert. I have edited and show the query.

Comment: You should use `PDO` and prepared statements when you work with DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like Shyman said, but wrap it in a function somewhere (class, functional) - to get params and assign a default value if not set:

```php
function getParam($name, $default = 'NA') {
    return isset($_POST[$name]) ? $_POST[$name] : $default;
}

$tgl_real = getParam('TGL_REAL');
$someNiceInteger = getParam('WHAT_THE_INT', 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a foreach at the start.

```
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value){
    if ($value==''){
        $_POST[$key]='NA';
    }
}
```

Something like that would help.

Answer (score 0):

while creating the database table you can set default constraint. for example

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
O_Id int NOT NULL,
OrderNo int NOT NULL,
P_Id int,
OrderDate date DEFAULT GETDATE()
)
```

hope it helps :)