# Set multiple variables to the same if they are not set

Tags: php, variables, foreach, default, isset

Is there a shorthand for the following:

```php
$a ??= []; # Note: $a ??= [] is equivalent to $a = isset($a) ? $a : []
$b ??= [];
#...
$z ??= [];
```

One possible solution is:

```php
foreach (array("a", "b", ..., "z") as $elem) {
  $$elem ??= [];
}
```

What I do not like about the approach above is that I am passing a list of strings to the foreach function rather than a list of variables - that would be inconvenient if the names of the variables were to change. Is there another more convenient solution?

Comment: Do these variables are previously known? Or you are looking for a kind of generic solution to avoid the undefined variables?

Comment: In the current implementation, the names of the variables are known. It would likely remain that way.

Comment: When you have to deal with an unwieldy volume of individual variables, it begs the question -- "Why not use an array to contain all variables so that you can enjoy array functions and sensible iteration techniques?"

Comment: Topically related: [Default value if variable not sets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12688603/2943403) and [How to set a default value for empty/missing POST fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36194504/2943403)

Comment: I wonder why you have this XY Problem.  Can you explain why you are confronted with this abnormal problem of individual variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use by reference variable-length argument lists: (PHP >= 7.4)

```
function defineVariables($default, &...$vars)
{
    foreach($vars as &$v)
        $v ??= $default;
}

defineVariables([], $a, $b, $c);
```

Comment: I cannot get this to work. [PHP Sandbox](https://onlinephp.io/c/98250)

Comment: This works well for me. [PHP Sandbox](https://onlinephp.io?s=XU3bCoMwFHsv9B8OpYhC8Qc2J7tfPmAvIuOoFQVXxdvL2L_v1DIYCwRCEpJ13FUdZxIhgkRsBUQbEDuhQOydPoh0RXm25EfnnWx-dvpi9dXp29LlrJxMPtatgUKXtdF37GvMGj34kgycmlGBF4ahnLEfAs5enAGhbHuNeeUvNuAAnpwDF1nIGeI4gu8EHb3t1_9FkiqQSMyIeUA1mnsU07Pzf-0P&v=8.2.13) It seems that most online PHP syntax analyzers doesn't quite understand this.

Comment: It works for me: [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/lQVSf) Ignore the error report on line 6. It also makes sense, if you read the code.

Comment: Okay. That is a good solution. The function could also be applied directly. [PHP Sandbox](https://onlinephp.io/c/82410)

Answer (score -1):

in php, you can achieve this using variable variables. here's a more concise and dynamic solution:

```
foreach (range('a', 'z') as $letter) {
    ${$letter} ??= [];
}
```

this code dynamically creates variables $a through $z and initializes them to an empty array if they are not already set. this way, you don't need to pass a list of variable names explicitly. Instead, it dynamically generates them based on the range of letters from 'a' to 'z'.

Comment: This solution has the same problem as the one above - it would be inconvenient if the names of the variables were to change. In my use case the variable names a, ..., z are placeholders for now.